# Template deduction from default argument

Tags: c++

Consider the following code section ([godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/JSKhDD))

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T = int{})
{}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

The code doesn't compile. The error message says that `T` couldn't be deduced, even though the default argument's type is known, so I would think that `T` would be deduced as `int`.

Why is this the case? Does template deduction take place before default arguments are substituted? If so is this specified in the standard, or is it implementation defined?

Note that the code does compile with `foo<int>();`.